# making matrix from dataframe to make heatmap in R

Tags: r

I want to make heatmap in R but I could not change the dataframe to appropriate matrix form. I have a dataframe with three columns (protein,value and treatments) in columns proteins and treatments I have some repeatation. could you someone help me how can I make appropriate matrix from this data and which package is better to make heatmap.(I have 1000 proteins (some of them are repeated according to various treatments) and 4 group of treatments).
I am beginner in R and really need your help. Thank you in advance.

```
example:
protein           value    treatment

EPN1              0.986    treat1

LAMB1             0.881    treat2

PKP4              0.827    treat2     
PKP2              0.739    treat3     
BAIAP2            0.519    treat2     
UTRN              0.502    treat4     
REPS2             0.481    treat2     
PKP4              0.365    treat1      
LAMC1            -0.529    treat2     
PPIB              2.86     treat4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some example data.

```
dat <- data.frame(
    protein=replicate(100, paste(sample(LETTERS, 4), collapse="")),
    value=rnorm(100),
    treatment=paste0("treat", sample(1:4, 100, replace=TRUE)),
    stringsAsFactors=FALSE
)
```

Using `ggplot2` you could do

```
library(ggplot2)
plt <- ggplot(dat, aes(treatment, protein, fill=value)) + geom_tile()
```

More options you can find here: https://www.r-graph-gallery.com/79-levelplot-with-ggplot2.html

However, I don't know how to deal with a lot of proteins to plot (as you mentioned). Do you need to see the names of the proteins?

EDIT:
one possibility for 1000 proteins would be to make the chart really long, like so:

```
ggsave(
    "long.pdf", plot=plt, device="pdf", 
    width=21, height=150, units="cm", limitsize=FALSE
)
```

This creates a PDF in the current folder. Using the zoom function of your PDF-Viewer, you can then navigate to the rows of interest.

EDIT 2: For more complex charts I (still) rely on base R. But maybe there are some ggplot-Style packages I am not aware of. A base R solution requires to convert the data into a matrix first. One approach would be to use a sparse matrix like this:

```
dim_x <- unique(dat$protein)
dim_y <- unique(dat$treatment)
map_x <- setNames(seq_along(dim_x), dim_x)
map_y <- setNames(seq_along(dim_y), dim_y)

library(Matrix)
mat <- sparseMatrix(
    i=map_x[dat$protein], j=map_y[dat$treatment], x=dat$value, 
    dims=c(length(dim_x), length(dim_y)), dimnames=list(dim_x, dim_y)
)
```

Then you can use the base R `heatmap` function,

```
heatmap(as.matrix(mat))
```

or some more customizeable function like

```
library(pheatmap)
pheatmap(mat)
```

which both show dendograms.

Comment: yes I need to have all protein names in one of axises.  it was done by your guidance and code. thanks. Is it possible to load dendogram on heatmap with this package?

Answer (score 2):

You may do either of these 2

```r
df <- read.table(header = T, text = "protein           value    treatment
EPN1              0.986    treat1
LAMB1             0.881    treat2
PKP4              0.827    treat2     
PKP2              0.739    treat3     
BAIAP2            0.519    treat2     
UTRN              0.502    treat4     
REPS2             0.481    treat2     
PKP4              0.365    treat1      
LAMC1            -0.529    treat2     
PPIB              2.86     treat4 ")

library(tidyverse)
df %>% ggplot(aes(x= treatment, y = protein, fill = value)) +
  geom_tile()
```

[image]

---

OR

```
library(echarts4r)

df |> 
  e_charts(protein) |> 
  e_heatmap(treatment, value) |> 
  e_visual_map(value)
```

[image]

Comment: this package (echarts4r) draw heatmap well but it does not show all proteins in the x axis. this is because of package limitation? it showed only 7 proteins. I need the name of all proteins in x axis.

Comment: That may not be a difficult job @mehdiheidari, moreover, the library gives interactive charts like giving nice tooltips, etc.